# Error during implementation of operator>> :C++ no operator matches these operands operand types are: std::istream >> const double error

Tags: c++, syntax-error, operator-overloading

Can't resolve this error,please help me.
I don't know what to try, I haven't done operator>> overloading before.
I can't figure out why I got this error.
If I resolve this, I want to read from file with this overload.

Here is the code:

```
#include "Diak.h"

Diak::Diak(string vn, string kn, double a)
{
    this->vnev = vn;
    this->knev = kn;
    this->atlag = a;
}

double Diak::getAtlag() const
{
    return this->atlag;
}

string Diak::getVnev() const
{
    return this->vnev;
}

string Diak::getKnev() const
{
    return this->knev;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Diak& diak)
{
    os << diak.vnev << " " << diak.knev << " " << diak.atlag << endl;

    return os;
}

istream& operator>>(istream& is, const Diak& diak)
{
    is >> diak.vnev >> diak.knev >> diak.atlag;

    return is;
}

bool operator<(const Diak& d1, const Diak& d2)
{
    if (d1.getVnev() < d2.getVnev())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if(d1.getKnev() == d2.getKnev())
    {
        if (d1.getKnev() < d2.getKnev())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Problem in this line:

```
is >> diak.vnev >> diak.knev >> diak.atlag;
```

[image]

Comment: `diak` is `const` which means its data members can't be modified by `is`. Remove the `const` to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to remove the const from the implementation and from the declaration(in the header file).